# editing an URL - how to?

Tags: android, url

I am working in this code where I want to edit an Url with an EditText and when I press the button that brings me the image. But I'm getting a mistake that saids that the EditText is sending a null value.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img;
Bitmap bitmap;
private Button btn;
EditText et_num;

String URLIMAGE = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num+".png";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    et_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_num);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new GetImageFromURL(img).execute(URLIMAGE);
        }
    });
}

public class GetImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView imgV;

    public GetImageFromURL(ImageView imgV) {
        this.imgV = imgV;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
        String urldisplay = url[0];
        bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream srt = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(srt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        imgV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
   }
 }
```

I'm getting this:

```
 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/null.png
```

Does anyone has an idea of ​​how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things wrong here.

First, you're hardcoding `URLIMAGE` at initialization, which means it'll take whatever the `et_num` variable is *at that point* and convert it to a String. Since it's null, the String representation is `null`.

The second problem is that `EditText#toString()` isn't how you get the text from an EditText instance. You should be using `EditText#getText().toString()`. So do two things:

1. Since you're only using `URLIMAGE` in one place, just move the assignment to your click listener.
2. Use `et_num.getText()` not `et_num`.

Your `onClick()` code should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String URLIMAGE = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num.getText()+".png";
   new GetImageFromURL(img).execute(URLIMAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got wrong here:

```
EditText et_num;
String URLIMAGE = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num+".png";
```

change to something like this:

```
String URLIMAGE = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    et_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_num);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
     URLIMAGE  = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num.getText().toString()+".png";
            new GetImageFromURL(img).execute(URLIMAGE);
        }
    });
}
```

**Added**

Remember:  You need to check nullPointerException for textView any time you want to get its value.

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(edt.getText().toString())){
 // Doing something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Place String URLIMAGE; (before onCreate)

2.Place you code inside `btn.setOnClickListener` also you need to get text from edit text.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
URLIMAGE = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num.getText().toString()+".png";

            new GetImageFromURL(img).execute(URLIMAGE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, is probably getting value provided in the EditText.

First of all the structure will always give you null, as et_num is not declared yet, so it will be always null in below scenario.

```
EditText et_num;
String URLIMAGE = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num+".png";
```

Change the URLIMAGE to `String URLIMAGE = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"`

Then in OnClickListener get the actual value of EditText and append to URL

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = et_num.getText().toString();
            new GetImageFromURL(img).execute(URLIMAGE + text + ".png");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, et_num is an Object(EditText) and not the text. During initialization your URLIMAGE initializes before you init your et_num, so it's null. Remove URLIMAGE at all and replace this:

```
new GetImageFromURL(img).execute(URLIMAGE);
```

with this:

```
String url = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num.getText()+".png";
new GetImageFromURL(img).execute(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

put this inside the `onClick()` method of the button `btn`

```
String URLIMAGE = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num.getText().toString()+".png";
```

like this

```
btn.setOnclicklistener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            String URLIMAGE = "https://www.avansys.edu.pe/sites/default/files/"+et_num.getText().toString()+".png";

            new GetImageFromURL(img).execute(URLIMAGE);
      }
       });
```